# how to differentiate between "implication" and" connotation"?

Tags: vocabulary, connotations, implication

While I have studied some resources as to these terms, in fact, I cannot yet get what could be considered as their difference. Or, when could they be interchangeable, when not?

Any comment would greatly be appreciated

Comment: do you have any further questions, or need any further clarification?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A connotation can just be an idea that we associate with another word, phrase or sentence. So for example the phrase *bucket and spade* will have connotations of beaches, sunshine, childhood, seaside holidays and so forth. If you're writer and you want to talk about a grave-robber stealing a body from a cemetery, you probably won't want to say:

- He picked up his bucket and spade ...

There's nothing wrong with the grammar of this sentence, but when you say *bucket and spade* it might make people think about happy things, not grave, serious and scary ones. It's probably important for your story for people to be a little bit scared, not happy and comfortable. Notice that nobody would think that the grave-robber was at the beach in that sentence. It is just that using that phrase will make people think about beaches for a second.

An implication is something slightly different. If I imply something, I am saying something specific to somebody, without actually using that sentence (this might be an accident. We might not want the listener to have this idea). Usually, an implication is a proposition -  something that can be expressed as a sentence. So for example, if I say:

- If you don't do your homework, you won't get any ice cream.

... then I am implying that:

- If you do your homework you *will* get some ice-cream.

But notice that I did not *say* that. That second sentence is not part of what I said. If I am a mean and horrible person, I may have deliberately tricked you. But I did not lie. The truth may well be that:

- If you don't do your homework you won't get any ice-cream and if you *do* do your homework, you still won't get any ice-cream.

The reason might be for example, that you are not allowed ice-cream because you're allergic to dairy products. Notice that if I say the whole of the last example, the implication is cancelled. We no longer think that the speaker will give any ice-cream to anyone if the homework is done. We can cancel implications easily. It is difficult to cancel connotations. We may still be reminded of something, like holidays, for example, even if the actual word or phrase is being used in a completely different way.

**Conclusion**

In the normal uses of these words, a connotation is an association that we have with a word, phrase or sentence. It is not necessarily a proposition. It is not usually the kind of idea we can express in a sentence.

In contrast, an implication is usually a proposition. It is an idea we could express as a sentence. Sometimes the listener may want us to understand this proposition. Sometimes it may be accidental. We can cancel implications. It is difficult, if not impossible sometimes, to cancel connotations.

Answer (score 2):

Implications and connotations are linked but not synonymous.  Let's start with some definitions:

> **Implication:** the conclusion that can be drawn from something although
> it is not explicitly stated.
>
> **Connotation:** an idea or feeling which a word invokes for a person in addition to its literal or primary meaning.

An easy example of an implication is when someone is being passive-aggressive.  They are heavily suggesting something but they don't actually say it.   When someone implies something, they assume that you understand what they mean without them saying it.  An example of this would be if you had three people living in a house (Amy, Bella and Caroline) and someone has eaten all the cake but no one is admitting it.  Say, Amy says to Caroline:

> "Caroline, When Bella and I went shopping, the whole cake was still there"

In this sentence Amy is **stating explicitly** that at the time she left the house, the whole cake was still uneaten.  However, she is **implying** that neither herself nor Bella are the cake thief because when they left the house, the cake had not been eaten yet.  She is **implying** that the cake was eaten while they were out of the house.  She may also be **implying** that Caroline is the cake thief because she is the only other suspect apart from Bella.

Connotations are meanings or associations outside of the literal meaning of the word.  An example of this would be the word 'hunt'.  Hunting has the definition of 'the activity of searching for something'.  However, 'hunting' has a negative connotations including the association with large animals hunting prey to kill and eat.  Connotations can be used to imply things:

> The cat was hunting the mouse.

Because the connotation of 'hunt then kill', this phrase implies that the mouse was in danger.  If there was no connotation of 'hunt then kill'.  I would be implying that mouse was hidden from the cat.